# How do I compare previous record with actual record?

Tags: php, html

I have a list with countries and cities, sorted by country. If the list starts a new country, I want there to be a extra breakline between them.

List shown on the site:

[image]

Have no clue how to do this.

Code I have now:

```
<?php
$resultaat = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM locatie_eu ORDER BY country, city ASC");
$rij = mysqli_fetch_array($resultaat);

while ($rij) {

  print($rij['vlag']);?> : <?php print($rij['country']);?>, <b><a href="<?php print($rij['link']);?>" target="new"><?php print($rij['city']);?></a></b><br>

  $rij = mysqli_fetch_array($resultaat);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This keeps track of the country on the previous line, and compares it to the current one, so you know when you add an extra line break.

```
$previousCountry = "";

while ($rij) {

  if ($previousCountry != "" && $previousCountry != $rij['country']) print "<br>";
  print($rij['vlag']);?> : <?php print($rij['country']);?>, <b><a href="<?php print($rij['link']);?>" target="new"><?php print($rij['city']);?></a></b><br>
  $previousCountry = $rij['country'];
  $rij = mysqli_fetch_array($resultaat);
}
```

Comment: this works, just one small correction so it works fine is to delete the ) after   $previousCountry = $rij['country'];

Comment: Yes sorry that was a typo, I have corrected it. Glad it helped you.